# /bin/sh: service: command not found on cent os 7

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile, newrelic

While building this command in Dockerfile:

```
RUN service start newrelic-infra
```

I am getting this error:

> /bin/sh: service: command not found  The command '/bin/sh -c service
>   start newrelic-infra' returned a non-zero code: 127

After inserting this `yum -y install initscripts && yum clean all` in Dockerfile and performing `RUN service start newrelic-infra`,
I am getting same error.

Comment: You should assume commands like `service` and `systemctl` just don't work in Docker.  Even if `RUN service start` didn't raise an error, the fact of the running process doesn't get persisted in the image; the next `RUN` command and any eventual `docker run` won't have that process running.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Could you please explain why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the following:

```
RUN yum update -y && yum install initscripts -y
```

At least this worked for me.
Also, there is a Github issue with more information that might help:
https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/issues/28